# How can I remove duplicates from an hash based on multiple keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have query that returns all IPS events in a 24 hour period and strings it together to display in my view. I'd like to remove duplicates based on `[sig_id,ips_attacker_ip,ips_target]` keys. Basically I'd like weed out all but 1 of 3000+ attempts if it was the same signature id from the same host to one server.

```
@events = IpsEvent.all(conditions: ['timestamp >= ?', ts]).reverse.uniq
# Start IPS Event txt display
@ips_events = []
@events.each do |events|
  ips_timestamp = events.timestamp
  ips_hostname = get_hostname(events.sid)
  sig_id = get_sig_sid(events.signature)
  sig_name = get_sig_name(events.signature)
  sig_protocol = get_event_protocol(events.sid, events.cid)

  if sig_protocol == 6
    sig_protocol = 'tcp'

  elsif sig_protocol == 17
    sig_protocol = 'udp'

  elsif sig_protocol == 1
    sig_protocol = 'icmp'

  elsif !sig_protocol
    sig_protocol = 'null'

  end

  ips_attacker_ip = get_attacker_ip(events.sid, events.cid).to_s(16).rjust(8,'0').scan(/.{2}/).map(&:hex).join('.')
  if get_event_protocol(events.sid, events.cid) == 6
    ips_attacker_port = get_tcp_sport(events.sid, events.cid)

  elsif get_event_protocol(events.sid, events.cid) == 17
    ips_attacker_port = get_udp_sport(events.sid, events.cid)

  elsif get_event_protocol(events.sid, events.cid) == 1
    'icmp'

  elsif !get_event_protocol(events.sid, events.cid)
    'null'

  end

  ips_target = get_target_ip(events.sid, events.cid).to_s(16).rjust(8,'0').scan(/.{2}/).map(&:hex).join('.')
  if get_event_protocol(events.sid, events.cid) == 6
    @ips_target_port = get_tcp_dport(events.sid, events.cid)

  elsif get_event_protocol(events.sid, events.cid) == 17
    ips_target_port = get_udp_dport(events.sid, events.cid)

  elsif get_event_protocol(events.sid, events.cid) == 1
    'icmp'

  elsif !get_event_protocol(events.sid, events.cid)
    'null'

  end

  @ips_events += [timestamp: ips_timestamp,hostname: ips_hostname,signature_id: sig_id,signature_name: sig_name,
                 protocol: sig_protocol, attacker: ips_attacker_ip,attacker_port: ips_attacker_port,
                 target: ips_target,target_port: ips_target_port]

end
# End IPS Event txt display
```

Here is the code from my view.

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <th>Timestamp</th>
        <th>Sensor Name</th>
        <th>Signature ID</th>
        <th>Signature Name</th>
        <th>Protocol</th>
        <th>Source IP</th>
        <th>Source Port</th>
        <th>Target IP</th>
        <th>Target Port</th>    
      </tr>

      <% @ips_events.each do |event| %>
      <tr>
        <td class='timestamp'><%= event[:timestamp] %></td>
        <td class='sensor_name'><%= event[:hostname] %></td>
        <td class='sig_id'><%= event[:signature_id] %></td>
        <td class='sig_name'><%= event[:signature_name] %></td>
        <td class='sig_protocol'><%= event[:protocol] %></td>
        <td class='src_ip'><%= event[:attacker] %></td>
        <td class='src_port'><%= event[:attacker_port] %></td>
        <td class='tgt_ip'><%= event[:target] %></td>
        <td class='tgt_port'><%= event[:target_port] %></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>

    </table>
```

Here is one of the hashes that get returned.

```
{:TIMESTAMP=>SUN, 20 JUL 2014 21:24:28 UTC +00:00, :HOSTNAME=>"VS-101-Z0:DNA0:DNA1", :SIGNATURE_ID=>10000001, :SIGNATURE_NAME=>"DROP - WP-ADMIN ATTEMPT", :PROTOCOL=>"TCP", :ATTACKER=>"203.195.184.151", :ATTACKER_PORT=>60521, :TARGET=>"172.31.251.13", :TARGET_PORT=>80}
```

Comment: Give a try to: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq

Comment: You're writing awfully unidiomatic Ruby. Please git rid of all the `then`'s and semicolons, it'll make it much easier for you to get help with your code.

Comment: removed the unidiomatic stuff, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a good spot for [Array#reject!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-reject-21). Given an array it takes a block and if you return false it will be removed from the array.

```
@events.reject! do |event|
  ...do your checking based on the keys here...
end
```